# crear un rectángulo al pulsar un botón en tintar

Tags: python, tkinter, botón, canvas

Buenas tardes a todos!

Estoy haciendo un programa más complejo y una parte lleva la creación de dibujos en tkinter.

Para ello me gustaría podre crear con un boton un rectangulo, para ir empezando.

El problema es que, aún al poner la función en el command del botón, el rectangulo se crea del tirón antes de yo pulsar el botón.

Aquí os dejo el código que he usado, por si me podéis echar una mano.

Un saludo y muchas gracias!

```
from tkinter import *
  
root = Tk() 
  
root.geometry('430x300') 
  
def crea(canvas):
    c.create_rectangle(10,10,100,100,fill="red")


c = Canvas(root, width=330, height=200, bg="blue") 
c.place(x=50, y=50) 
btn = Button(root, text='Prueba', width=5, height=10, bd='10', command=crea(c)) 
  
btn.place(x=75, y=150) 

  
root.mainloop()
```

lo que se me crea es lo siguiente, antes de pulsar el botón

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Cuando la función que vas a utilizar con `command` tiene argumentos debes utilizar `lambda`

```
btn = Button(root, text='Prueba', width=5, height=10, bd='10', command=lambda: crea(c))
```

De esa forma funcionará correctamente

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por contestar!!
Se me había pasado por completo el lambda. Un millón de gracias!

Comment: @joanto56, si larespuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.